# Why mysqlbinlog displays [replace into] row events as below

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog

AS we know from

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the
>   table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE
>   index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

When I use an account which has  no privileges to delete  to execute replace into ,it reminded me of delete privilege.

However when I use mysqlbinlog to see the contents in the binlog,it confused me.

An example is as follows:

binlog_format=row

```
root:test> show create table t3\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t3
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `t3` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `c1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c2` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `c3` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uidx_c1` (`c1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 15 |    5 | bb   | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

**Case 1:**

```
root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 15 |    5 | bb   | NULL |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)

root:test> 
root:test> replace into t3 (c1,c2,c3) values(5,'bb',3);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 16 |    5 | bb   |    3 |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysqlbinlog displays as below:

```
# at 15126
#161019 15:04:14 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15190 CRC32 0x9bab83d9    Update_rows: table id 234 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE `test`.`t3`
### WHERE
###   @1=15
###   @2=5
###   @3='bb'
###   @4=NULL
### SET
###   @1=16
###   @2=5
###   @3='bb'
###   @4=3
# at 15190
#161019 15:04:14 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15221 CRC32 0x70a88be3    Xid = 177
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

The mysqlbinlog doesn't display delete and insert .

**Case 2: auto_increment=17**

```
root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 16 |    5 | bb   |    3 |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root:test> replace into t3 (id,c1,c2,c3) values(17,5,'bb',3);
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 17 |    5 | bb   |    3 |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysqlbinlog displays as below:

```
# at 15408
#161019 15:13:18 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15476 CRC32 0xe200a811    Update_rows: table id 234 flags: STMT_END_F
### UPDATE `test`.`t3`
### WHERE
###   @1=16
###   @2=5
###   @3='bb'
###   @4=3
### SET
###   @1=17
###   @2=5
###   @3='bb'
###   @4=3
# at 15476
#161019 15:13:18 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15507 CRC32 0xe02d7749    Xid = 179
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

The mysqlbinlog doesn't display delete and insert .

**Case 3:auto_increment=18**

```
root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 17 |    5 | bb   |    3 |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

root:test> replace into t3 (id,c1,c2,c3) values(17,5,'cc',4);  
Query OK, 2 rows affected (0.01 sec)

root:test> select * from t3;
+----+------+------+------+
| id | c1   | c2   | c3   |
+----+------+------+------+
|  1 |    1 | a    |    1 |
|  2 |    2 | a    |    1 |
|  8 | NULL | NULL |    1 |
| 14 |    4 | bb   | NULL |
| 17 |    5 | cc   |    4 |
+----+------+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

mysqlbinlog displays as below:

```
# at 15745
#161019 15:30:49 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15796 CRC32 0x258b633a    Write_rows: table id 234 flags: STMT_END_F
### DELETE FROM `test`.`t3`
### WHERE
###   @1=17
###   @2=5
###   @3='bb'
###   @4=3
### INSERT INTO `test`.`t3`
### SET
###   @1=17
###   @2=5
###   @3='cc'
###   @4=4
# at 15796
#161019 15:30:49 server id 22100  end_log_pos 15827 CRC32 0xcc4e1740    Xid = 183
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

The mysqlbinlog displays delete and insert .

Stated thus, it seems when the primary key value is the same ,the binlog use delete+insert .If the primary key value is not the same ,the binlog use update.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using row based replicates, as opposed to statement based.

With row based replication you'll only see the *effect of the change* as it was executed on the master. One statement can lead to several rows changes as you would see if you ran `update t3 set c3 = 1;` to change all 5 rows.

Comment: Thank you  and yes,the binlog_format=row. But case 3,it use delete+insert ,however case 1 and case 2 use update.It  confused me .